# Why this difference of 25?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

The numbers 4962, 29922, 179862, and 1389858 share a curious property and I am wondering if someone can enlighten me.  The largest prime factor of each number differs, by 25, from the remainder of the number after division by the sum of all of its prime divisors.  My question is why does this difference of 25 arise?

With s(n) being a function that returns the sum of all of the prime factors of n (AKA sopfr(n)), here is a breakdown of the numbers:

-n-          -Divisors of n-     -n mod s(n)-

4962        (2,3,827)              802
(802 + 25 = 827)

29922      (2,3,4987)            4962
(4962 + 25 = 4987)

179682    (2,3,29947)           29922
(29922 + 25 = 29947(

1389858  (2,3,231643)         231618
(231618 + 25 = 321643)

These numbers can be found in OEIS sequence A238530.  The reason they form a sequence is because if you call sopfr(n) from within a recursive function like this:

def sd(n):
    d = 1
    s = n % sopfr(n)
    if s > 1:
        d += sd(s)
    return d

the output of sd() forms the sequence of recursion depths of n, for n=2,3,4,... (OEIS A238529)  The numbers above are the first occurrences of a number with depth 6, 7, 8, and 10, respectively.

Comment: I don't find the OEIS sequence you refer to matching your description.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: @Ross:  Sorry.  I forgot the sequences weren't published yet.  They should be soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your examples are of the form $6p$ for a prime $p$.  The sum of  prime divisors of this number is $p+5$ and $6p \equiv 6p-5(p+5) = p-25 \pmod {p+5}$.  It will work the same for any prime greater than $25$

Comment: Thank you.  If you care to, you could create an OEIS account and add your explanation to the "Comments" section of the draft edit of A238530.  If not, I will do so.

Comment: I have an account, but I can't see your sequence.  I'm not sure it is that interesting to have all numbers of the form  $6p$ for $p \gt 25$

Comment: The sequence, so far, is (2, 8, 22, 166, 788, 4962, 29922, 179682, 688078, 7060198) -- they are not all of the form 6p. They are just record setters. E.g. the third term = 22 because 22 mod 11+2 = 9 -> 9 mod 3+3 = 3 -> 3 mod 3 = 0, and 22 is the smallest number with a depth of 3.  That said, it may still not be an interesting sequence. :)